# how to find units for the ring Z[1/2]

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

where Z[1/2] is a set: {a/2^n | a is integer and n is natural number}.

I know to find a unit, we need to find a u in Z[1/2] such that u*b=1, where b is in Z[1/2].
but if I say the unit is u = 2^n/a, which satisfies u*b=1, but it cannot guarantee that u is in Z[1/2]

So how should I find the units in this case?

Comment: $2^n / a$ is an element of the ring if and only if $a$ is a power of 2. Can you conclude?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: "it cannot guarantee that u is in Z[1/2]": so, what is the necessary and sufficient condition (on $a$) to guarantee that? P.S. Don't listen to that Community Bot, it seems deaf. And correct @Crostul's hint, $a$ may be $<0.$

Answer (score 2):

The units of $\mathbb{Z}[1/2]$ are precisely the signed powers of two and their opposites, that is: $$\mathcal{U}_{\mathbb{Z}[1/2]} = \{(-1)^n2^k:n\in\mathbb{N},k\in\mathbb{Z}\}$$
We can prove this via double inclusion.

Every $a$ of the form $(-1)^n2^k$ can be multiplied by $(-1)^n2^{-k}$ to obtain 1. So $a$ is a unit.

Now suppose $b\in\mathcal{U}_{\mathbb{Z}[1/2]}$. There must exist $c\in\mathbb{Z}[1/2]$ such that $bc=1$. Say $b=B/2^k$ and $c=C/2^\ell$. Then $BC=2^{k+\ell}$ which means that both $B$ and $C$ are signed powers of two or their opposites. We can conclude that $b$ and $c$ are in the set $\{(-1)^n2^k:n\in\mathbb{N},k\in\mathbb{Z}\}$.